# How to find external ip address a payload uses to connect back to the attacker?

Tags: android, metasploit, meterpreter

I find myself targeted with a malicious .apk file. I am provided with some malicious files disguised as a genuine .apk.

I used apktool to decompile the file and collect some information about the attacker. I could find none (please point me how to find some info if any can be found)

Could you point me in the right direction as to find which ip does the payload uses to connect back to the attacker? And also monitor the attacker if I deliberately allow the attacker to get a meterpreter session.

What else can I do to make the attacker regret targeting me?

Note:
I am aware of how to generate a payload, embed it to a genuine apk file and to use a meterpreter session to access data from the remote target.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wireless hotspot using your laptop, connect your phone on the wireless created by your laptop and then use wireshark to capture traffic from your phone to the internet. Then you will be able to see all the IPs your phone is connecting to.

Here's some useful links:

- [How to create a hotspot on linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap)
- [How to use wireshark](http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/)

Comment: Ideally you'd do this from a test device and not from one that has any of your real personal data on it! Should go without saying but you are otherwise literally intentionally running malware on your device.

Comment: @Mathew, I am well aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

create android os on virtual box or vmware that has internet connection.
install the apk.
cek the ip traffic.